# Laravel auth()->id() not working in prod server

Tags: php, laravel

I have one seperate database for saving logs
I have middleware that saves every request with response

```php
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $logType)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        CreateLog::dispatch($request, $response, $logType)->onQueue(config('queue.queues.logging'));
        return $response;
    }
```

Everything related to auth progress works after every work complated. beacuse u used         $response = $next($request);

```php
'user_id' => auth()->id(),
```

Trying to save user_id like that. Everything is working perfect
But in prod server user_id is being null

In prod server project running using docker

Comment: If your production server is using a different queue type than your local server (redis or database vs sync), it may not have access to `Auth`. You might be able to get it from `$request->user->id`, or pass the auth id in with your dispatch data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to double check multiple things:

- what session driver are you using?
- what is the queue driver are you using?
- is your middleware runs after session and auth middleware runs ( based on the configuration in `kernal.php` )

based on your question and the problem is happening only on production so probably your issue is communication, your queue handler can't access session data which is usually the case if you separate them into different modules and connections to improve performance so to achieve this you need to pass the information you need from one module to another so in your case

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $logType)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $userID = auth()->id();
        CreateLog::dispatch($request, $response, $logType, $userID)->onQueue(config('queue.queues.logging'));
        return $response;
    }
```

and in your `CreateLog` you store this userID and use it instead of depending on the `auth`

Answer (score 0):

The handle method of a queued job has no access to the authenticated user.

You should pass the value into the job instead of trying to resolve it within the job.

Pass the user id (and the request object) directly into the dispatch and then save it to job attributes within the job's constructor.

Also, do not pass the $next middleware to the queued job. This should be run directly in the request cycle not deferred in a job.